# How to click on the psuedo element that has a pop up checkbox element in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, automation-testing

I am trying to automate test script and ran upon the pseudo element which seems to not clickable using normal element finders. The element to be clicked is a field after which the checkbox pop which is to be clicked again.

```html
<span class="mat-select-placeholder mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c156-64 ng-star-inserted">
:before==$0
</span>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEq2v.png)

I have tried to click it using Actions method and JavascriptExecutor but was not able to. Please help.

This is the codes that I have tried.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mat-select-placeholder mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c211-60 ng-star-inserted']").click();
```

Comment: Is that locator getting identified? If span didn't work, try with previous divs. Mostly jsClick, actionClick should work.

Comment: It did not work with JavascriptExecutor and Actions Methods as well. Thank you though

Comment: Then, that could be native elements too. Try mimicking the keyboard actions like clicking on "Enter" button.